# Does Decimal.Parse() support scientific notation?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Parse a Number from Exponential Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879463/c-parse-a-number-from-exponential-notation)

I currently have:

```
decimal value = Decimal.Parse(dataRow["column"].ToString());
```

There is some data in the backend that is in scientific notation (ie 3.2661758893885E-05) and which is causing a FormatException on the parse.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Decimal.Parse(strExpression, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowExponent));
```

Comment: This might not work for values like 5.363E-05