# 1E-08 to decimal

Tags: c#, decimal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse a Number from Exponential Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879463/parse-a-number-from-exponential-notation)
>   [Does Decimal.Parse() support scientific notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916921/does-decimal-parse-support-scientific-notation)

I am trying to convert such values as 1E-08 to a decimal in C# because decimals are the preffered datatype for handling funds yet I get an error upon decimal.Parse() "Input string was not in a correct format." wouldn't converting to float first and then to decimal defeat the purpose?

Comment: Are you actually trying to convert the string `1E-08` to a `decimal`?

Comment: Are you sure that isn't `0x1E - 0x08`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with :-

```
 decimal x = decimal.Parse("1E-08", NumberStyles.Float);
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, converting to float would indeed defeat the purpose. The good thing is, you don't have to do that here!

You can use an overload for Parse that takes a NumberStyles specifier:

```
decimal d = decimal.Parse("1E-08",
     System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowExponent);
```

Of course, if you are merely specifying a hard-coded decimal, you can use the decimal literal format:

```
decimal d = 1E-08M;
```

Comment: Even though I am greatful for the explanation System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowExponent doesn't work

Comment: @user1841964 it is working fine for me. Prints `0,00000001`