# Convert numbers with exponential notation from string to double or decimal

Tags: c#, .net, exponent

Is there a fast way to convert numbers with exponential notation (examples: "0.5e10" or "-5e20") to decimal or double?

**Update:** I found [Parse a Number from Exponential Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879463/c-sharp-parse-a-number-from-exponential-notation) but the examples won't work for me unless I specified a culture.

Solution:

```
double test = double.Parse("1.50E-15", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: You can use the following: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.exp.aspx

Comment: @Ramhound: That's non-ideal for a number of reasons; not to mention is use expensive floating-point operations, is unnecessarily convoluted, and is designed for a much more general x ^ y operation where x and y are both reals.

Comment: Have you tryied double.TryParse and decimal.TryParse?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If your culture uses `.` as the decimal separator, just `double.Parse("1.50E-15")` should work.

If your culture uses something else (e.g. `,`) or you want to make sure your application works the same on every computer, you should use [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx):

```
double.Parse("1.50E-15", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Already figured this out, but this was the first working answer.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed. Next time, you should post the solution as an answer and not edit the question.

Answer (score 10):

The standard [`double.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse.aspx) or [`decimal.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.parse.aspx) methods do the job here.

Examples:

```
// AllowExponent is implicit
var number1 = double.Parse("0.5e10");
Debug.Assert(number1 == 5000000000.0);

// AllowExponent must be given explicitly
var number2 = decimal.Parse("0.5e10", NumberStyles.AllowExponent);
Debug.Assert(number2 == 5000000000m);
```

Also, see the MSDN article [*Parsing Numeric Strings*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbtzcc4w.aspx) for more information. As long as the `NumberStyles.AllowExponent` option is specified to the `Parse` method (which it is by default for `double`), parsing such strings will work fine.

**NB:** As the questioner points out, the exponential notation of "e10" for example does not work in all cultures. Specifying en-US culture however ensures that it works. I suspect `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` should also do the trick.

Comment: @Dylan double test = double.Parse("1.509e10", NumberStyles.Float); // "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: For `decimal.Parse` you need to specify the NumberStyles explicitly.

Comment: @OMGKurtNilsen: Why are you specifying NumberStyles explicitly there? There's no need. If you insist on specifying explicitly, include `NumberStyles.AllowExponent` too.

Comment: I think this wouldn't work because of my culture. When I specified "en-US" culture it worked.

Comment: @OMGKurtNilsen: Makes sense... InvariantCulture might work too.

Comment: It did work. Will edit my solution. You should also add it to your answer.

Comment: @OMGKurtNilsen: Done. Hopefully that's enough for an acceptance now. :-) Ta.

Answer (score 2):

@Noldorin is correct try this code:

```
string str = "-5e20";
double d = double.Parse(str);
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming. This should probably belong as a comment though, as it's just re-iterating what I've done. :-)

Comment: I know I did originally add as comment but then realised you couldnt put a code block in a comment

Comment: No worries. Feel free to edit my answer, after all (you have the privelege at your rep yes?). If not, the example is there now. We probably added them at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

the [Math.Round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx) does it well, it will reder the number so that will remove, here is how to use it:

```
Math.Round(Double.Parse("3,55E-15"),2)
```