# convert numeric + alphabetical string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to convert the exponent value into equivalent .Net Datatype value.
Does anyone know how to convert numeric + alphabetical string into long or int?

```
Example of a string : 3e317188a00577
```

Comment: What's the result and why?

Comment: But this example is not a valid `long` or `int`.

Comment: what format is the string? looks like hexadecimal? If so, then there's plenty of answers already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/c-sharp-convert-integer-to-hex-and-back-again

Comment: Do you want to remove alphabets from this string and convert remaining characters into a nummber?

Comment: FYI: Numeric + alphabetical is usually called alphanumeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to extract digits only to create a `long`? You could use `Char.IsDigit` and LINQ:

```
Char[] digitsOnly = "3e317188a00577".Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray();
if(digitsOnly.Length > 0)
{
    long result;
    if (long.TryParse(new string(digitsOnly), out result))
    {
        Console.Write("Successfully parsed to: " + result);
    }
}
```

Result: `Successfully parsed to: 331718800577`

If you instead want to parse it from hexadecimal to int/long:

```
long result = long.Parse("3e317188a00577", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Result: `17505812249314679`

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies! I got some inspiration thanks to all of you. Tim Schmelter your solution worked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

if you want only numbers from string as long, then try this:

```
longValue = Long.parseLong("3e317188a00577".replaceAll("\\D+",""), 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

The string you gave us looks like a hex value to me. In that case you can convert it to an int/long like this:

```
string numberAsHex = "3e317188a00577";
long numberAsInt = long.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question:
[Convert numbers with exponential notation from string to double or decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877855/convert-numbers-with-exponential-notation-from-string-to-double-or-decimal)

The way to do it is :

```
String myString = "3e317188a00577";
Double myDouble = double.Parse(myString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```