# How to convert E+ number from a string to decimal in C#?

Tags: c#, formatting, decimal

In my application I get a number 2.424242E+08 in my label called lbl_price and when i try to convert it to a decimal i get a FormatEception. How can i fix this?

```
decimal newVat = Convert.ToDecimal(lbl_price.text);
```

Comment: If you're going to ask people how to fix something, you have to explain what the problem is with the result you're getting and/or what the desired result is.

Comment: [Convert numbers with exponential notation from string to double or decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877855/convert-numbers-with-exponential-notation-from-string-to-double-or-decimal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
decimal newVat = decimal.Parse(lbl_price.text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
```