# Converting Scientific notation values into numeric one while reading csv file which is serialized automatically

Tags: c#, csv, console-application, inputstreamreader

I have a csv file which I have to import into data base. When reading the file by stream reader, some values are converted into scientific notation like "5.00E+11". I have to restore this into original values. This is being done by a job, so I can not format the cell to "text" or "special" manually. When that cell is formatted as "text" or "special" it is working fine.

I need result as follows :

```
    "5.00E+11" should be converted into "500000000000"
    "8.12E+12" should be converted into "8122280000000"
```

My code for reading the file is as below:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This is used to read the csv file
    /// </summary>
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(comepleteFilePath))
    {
       values = reader.ReadToEnd()
                      .Split(new string[] 
                      { Environment.NewLine },
                       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
                      ).ToList();
     }         

    var _tempNuber = Convert.ToString(splits[13].Trim());
```

like below

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert numbers with exponential notation from string to double or decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877855/convert-numbers-with-exponential-notation-from-string-to-double-or-decimal)

Comment: Not duplicate exactly, it is issue of reading values which is serialized by excel automatically and same field have different type of data as well.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should use a dedicated *CSV* parser like *CsvHelper*, this will potentially save you a lot of time.

Secondly, if you want to parse a number use something like `decimal`, or `double` `Parse` with one of the options. In this case `NumberStyles.Float`

```
decimal.Parse(number, NumberStyles.Float);
```

[NumberStyles.Float](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Indicates that the `AllowLeadingWhite`, `AllowTrailingWhite`,
>   `AllowLeadingSign`, `AllowDecimalPoint`, and `AllowExponent` styles are
>   used. This is a composite number style.
>
> **AllowExponent**
>
> Indicates that the numeric string can be in exponential notation. The
>   AllowExponent flag allows the parsed string to contain an exponent
>   that begins with the "E" or "e" character and that is followed by an
>   optional positive or negative sign and an integer. In other words, it
>   successfully parses strings in the form nnnExx, nnnE+xx, and nnnE-xx.
>   It does not allow a decimal separator or sign in the significand or
>   mantissa; to allow these elements in the string to be parsed, use the
>   AllowDecimalPoint and AllowLeadingSign flags, or use a composite style
>   that includes these individual flags.

**Update**

you can either use regex to try and determine if the field does contain an actual number. Like `\d.\d+E[+-]\d+` or even better just use `decminal.TryParse` with the appropriate options.

Comment: That field is not only numeric; some data are text and some are numeric and some are combination of both text and numeric so I can not hard code any formatter directly. Issue are only with large numeric values.

Comment: I have to check if it is a numeric value and in scientific notation as well then have to use : decimal.Parse(number, NumberStyles.Float);

Comment: @SatishChandraMaurya `decminal.TryParse` will do both

Answer (score 1):

You can parse that string to decimal

```
    string s = "5.00E+11";
    decimal d = decimal.Parse(s, NumberStyles.Float);
```

Output

```
500000000000
```

If you want to apply parsing only one exponential element, then you can check given string is exponential or not

```
double d = 0;
if(str.Contains("E") && double.TryParse(str, out d))
{
   //Your conversion
}
```

POC : [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CcQPaO)

Comment: I can not check for "E" since a text value might contain that character also. So I have to check for "+" char instead of that ie. str.Contains("+")

Comment: I have additional condition check of `TryParse` that is important to check that passed string is of double type and Exp number always contains `+ and E/e`

Answer (score 0):

Check if that field is numeric and in scientific notation as well then format as :

```
var _tempNuber =  splits[13].Trim().Contains('+') ? decimal.Parse(splits[13].Trim(), NumberStyles.Float).ToString() 
                                                  : splits[13].Trim();
```

Comment: What if `splits[13]` contains something like `1+2`

Comment: No chance since no special characters are allowed there

Comment: Your last comment is contradictory as you mentioned exponential number in question (it contains `+`  in string) and in last statement you said no special characters... 
I don;t khow what values present in `splits[13]`, but solution suggested by you in an answer is not sustainable (I believe) if it works for you then I am happy about your answer

Comment: @Prasad let me clear; In database table from where the data is exported into the csv file, special characters are not allowed into that column from front end of the application. Now in Cell[13] of csv file the value is "500000000000" but when I read that field by above code, it is being read as "5.00E+11" due to automatic serialization of excel automatically.