# Input String was not in a correct format error from Decimal.Parse when precision is greater than 4

Tags: c#, type-conversion, decimal

I am having an issue in C# trying to convert a decimal using `Decimal.Parse` with a decimal precision of 4 or more. It is throwing the error:

> Input string was not in a correct format" when it tries to execute the
>   function with the value 0.00006 or greater precision.

I have tried using `InvariantCulture` and ruled that out as the issue, as that is what I saw being recommended for others getting this error.

I have also tried using `decimal.Parse` to no avail.

The line of code being executed is:

```
Decimal decVal = Decimal.Parse(Value.ToString())
```

where value is the string "0.00006".

Has anyone else seen this problem before? Is this a problem inherent with the `Decimal.Parse` function, or is it something that I am doing?

Comment: Works for me - it's likely a culture issue (or there are non-visible characters in the string)

Comment: I edited your code a tad to use formatting, and in the process I swapped out one line of English description with a variable. Was everything I did correct, and does this code still reproduce your problem? I hate to change code this dramatically, but it needed to be formatted so I wanted to double-check.

Comment: Programmers that call ToString() on a string do tend to have odd problems.  Is it actually a string?

Comment: @HansPassant If I had to guess I'd say it was a float. The `ToString()` call would result in scientific notation at that precision which would fail on the `decimal.Parse`

Comment: @DStanley How would I know if there are non-visible characters in the string? In the debugger it looks like it is just that string, but is it still possible there could be extra characters in there somehow that I am not seeing? petelids and Hans Passant I don't think it is a float, I tried casting into a Decimal and that did not work which would work if it were a float. It is an object which is a string. The odd thing is it will work with any decimal precision below 4, so it is something about the amount of precision that is causing it to error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out the ToString was returning scientific notation when precision goes beyond 4 places, so the fix was to use the following code:

```
Decimal decVal = Decimal.Parse(Value.ToString(), NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint)
```

Figured it out from reading through this question:
 [How to convert this scientific notation to decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587588/how-to-convert-this-scientific-notation-to-decimal)

Thanks to everyone who offered input!

Comment: Awesome, not that you may mark your own answer as the correct answer to your question?