# Decimal.Parse and Double.Parse System.FormatException Different behavior

Tags: c#, .net, number-formatting, formatexception

I do not understand why I have to specify `NumberStyles.Float` when using `decimal.Parse` and not for `double.Parse`

I can do:

```
var tmp = double.Parse("1e-2");
```

but not:

```
var tmp1 = decimal.Parse("1e-2");
```

Because a `System.FormatException` (Input string was not in a correct format) is thrown

```
var tmp1 = decimal.Parse("1e-2", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
```

someone can tell me if there is a good reason behind this behavior

Comment: Your screenshots seem to show a failure on line 15 *regardless* of what you're specifying. Your last one appears to show a problem on line 15 despite line 14 doing exactly the same operation. Really?

Comment: @JonSkeet I know, it's crazy. they are real. I'm not joking

Comment: Jon Skeet has an explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879463/parse-a-number-from-exponential-notation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just behaving as documented. From [`Double.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt.aspx):

> The s parameter is interpreted using a combination of the NumberStyles.Float and NumberStyles.AllowThousands flags.

Note that `NumberStyles.Float` includes `NumberStyles.AllowExponent`.

From [`Decimal.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cafs243z.aspx):

> Parameter s is interpreted using the NumberStyles.Number style.

`NumberStyles.Number` does *not* include `NumberStyles.AllowExponent`.

I can't reproduce your bizarre stack traces which appear to show the same call failing just after it's worked:

- `Decimal.Parse("1e-2")` always fails for me
- `Decimal.Parse("1e-2", NumberStyles.Float)` always works for me
- `Double.Parse("1e-2")` always works for me
- `Double.Parse("1e-2", NumberStyles.Float)` always works for me

As for why the "default" number style differs between the two - I suspect it's because `double` values typically *are* used in scientific scenarios where exponent-based representations are common, but `decimal` values typically aren't.

Comment: Yes I know. I'm asking why this different behavior

Comment: @giammin: It would have been helpful if you'd said that beforehand - essentially you're asking why the default number formats are different, but your question doesn't ask that. I've added one paragraph at the end of my answer to suggest a possible reason.

Comment: Right: I modified my question to make it more clear. +1 for your answer! It is resonable. maybe it is from a performance point of view

Comment: @giammin: It sounds like you've actually got *two* questions then: 1) Why are the default styles different between the two types; 2) Why are you seeing odd behaviour. I've no idea about the latter, but I suspect it's not actually running the code you've got. I suggest you add extra diagnostic lines to prove that - and try to reproduce the problem in a console app. I also suggest you ask one question per post...