# Error While Using Math.Round

Tags: c#

i am working on a problem to round decimal values everything is fine but at one certain point it gives me error input string was not formatted after debugging my code i found 4.90702817E-05 this which gives me error on this calling code . It converts all code but throws exception when it finds above string .

```
 MarketValue = Convert.ToDecimal(row["MarketValue"].ToString()) ,
```

Comment: `throws exception` - What exception it is throwing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse a Number from Exponential Notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879463/parse-a-number-from-exponential-notation)

Comment: What is the real type contained in that `row["MarketValue"]`? To put it differently: do you really need a `.ToString` followed by `Convert` or `Parse`, or would a plain cast work (`(decimal)row[".."]`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to Decimal by using below code. After getting the Value in Decimal form round it up.

```
decimal d = Decimal.Parse("4.90702817E-05", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
```

Comment: as you are getting  the number as a scientific notation it is not able to round up directly. So convert that number to the original Decimal number and then you can manipulate as you wish.

Comment: Mark your answer is same which i did MarketValue = decimal.Parse(row["MarketValue"].ToString(), NumberStyles.Float).

Comment: no there is bit change as compare to your previous answer. just check it clearly.i test that it is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
  MarketValue = Decimal.Parse(row["MarketValue"].ToString(), NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);
```

Comment: @rughes, its better if you have mentioned in comment rather than posting as a new answer!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the exception could be that the value is not a valid `decimal`.

The following code uses a method called `TryParse(...)`. This method returns `false` if the value is not a valid `decimal`, rather than throwing an exception.

For example:

```
decimal d = 0;
if (Decimal.TryParse(row["MarketValue"].ToString(), out d))
{
    MarketValue = d;
}
```

Comment: i tried this one it worked MarketValue = decimal.Parse(row["MarketValue"].ToString(), NumberStyles.Float),

Comment: Wonderful. Please don't forget to mark the correct answer as such!

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to use TryParse using following NumberStyles

```
    decimal d = 0;
    if (Decimal.TryParse(row["MarketValue"].ToString(), NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out d))
    {
        MarketValue = d;
    }
```