# Print 95 factorial as a number and not as exponential function

Tags: c#, types, factorial

When the input is `25` the expected output is `15511210043330985984000000` and not `1.551121e+25`. The parsing though is solved by `Decimal.Parse(factorial.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float)`.

I cannot get to calcuate for bigger numbers like 95.

```
using System;

namespace bigNumber
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            long factorial = 1;

            for (int i = number; i > 0; i--)
            {
                factorial = factorial * i;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(factorial);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse a Number from Exponential Notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879463/parse-a-number-from-exponential-notation)

Comment: Look at BigInteger structure https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=VS.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated above, the [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Numerics.BigInteger);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) is a good candidate, as it can hold an arbitrarily large signed integer:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    using System;
    using System.Numerics;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Factorial(0));

            Console.WriteLine(Factorial(25));

            Console.WriteLine(Factorial(95));
        }

        private static BigInteger Factorial(int number)
        {
            BigInteger factorial = 1;

            for (var i = number; i > 0; i--)
            {
                factorial *= i;
            }

            return factorial;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
1
15511210043330985984000000
10329978488239059262599702099394727095397746340117372869212250571234293987594703124871765375385424468563282236864226607350415360000000000000000000000
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `BigInteger` in your solution:

```
using System.Numerics;
using System.Linq; 
...
int n = 95;

BigInteger factorial = Enumerable
  .Range(1, n)
  .Select(x => (BigInteger) x)
  .Aggregate((f, v) => f * v);

Console.WriteLine(factorial);
```

Answer is

> 10329978488239059262599702099394727095397746340117372869212250571234293987594703124871765375385424468563282236864226607350415360000000000000000000000

note, that the `factorial` is far *beyond* `long.MaxValue`

Answer (score 1):

The BigInteger class from .Net 4.0+ supports arbitrarily large integers, int is relatively limiting in how many significant digits it represents.

Comment: BigInteger is older than that, added in 4.0 IIRC, and it's a struct, not a class.