# decimals with exponential noations

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, decimal, exponential

I'm reading a txt file containing + & - decimals which may contain exponential notations:

```
6.636666E-08
0
-5.5
2.2
```

I need to order the decimals then write them back to a different txt file.

I'm using `decimal.Parse()` to add the decimals into a dictionary, then I order them.
When I do that I lose the exponential notaions.

`decimal.Parse()` converts 6.636666E-08 to :  0.00000006636666

I need to write the original values as they were(just ordered).

How can I do that efficiently efficiently ?

How can I round the exponential notation issue ?
The file might contain thousands of lines, `is decimal.Parse()` an efficient  way of doing it?

Thank you

Comment: What language are you using?!  Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879463/parse-a-number-from-exponential-notation) answer your question?

Comment: I'm using c#.
I'm using decimal d = Decimal.Parse("6.636666E-08",System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
That converts 6.636666E-08 to 0.00000006636666 which is fine for my ordering but then I need to write it to the txt file
 in its original format i.e. 6.636666E-08
How can I convert 0.00000006636666 back to 6.636666E-08 ?
Is there a way of doing all this efficiently ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code? One way to do it is to have a list of tuples that you sort, one is the parsed decimal, the other is a string. Sort the decimal, and then print the string to file (Assuming the notation is not predictable - if it's predictable, write a helper when you print it to format it to whatever it should be)

Answer (score 3):

> I need to order the decimals then write them back to a different txt file.

If you need to *guarantee* that the written values are *exactly* as they appear in the source, then keep them as strings and order them by the parsed value:

```
var a = {read lines to string array}
var q = a.OrderBy(s => decimal.Parse(s));

foreach(string s in q)
    // write s
```

Also, don't use a dictionary if need to order the values - dictionaries are unordered by design.